# Using next string in list in function: python

Tags: python, list, variables

Using the Codecademy pyglatin.py translator as an example, I am trying to expand the translator to include multiple words at a time. 
So far, it reads the first word and translates it, and I would like to continue onto the next word, and then the next, until no more words exist. I would then like to print the entire original translated input.

def piglatin():

```
pig = 'ay'

original = raw_input('Enter a phrase:').split(' ')

if len(original[0]) > 0 and original[0].isalpha():
    word = original[0].lower()
    first = word[0]
    if first == "a" or first == "e" or first == "i" or first == "o" or first =="u":
        new_word = word + pig
        print new_word
    else:
        new_word = word[1:] + word[0:1] + pig
        print new_word
        again = raw_input('Translate again? Y/N')
        print again

        if len(again) > 0 and again.isalpha():
            second_word = again.lower()
            if second_word == "y":
                return piglatin()
            else:
                print "Okay Dokey!"

else:
    print 'Letters only please!'
    return piglatin()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want a `for` loop. A good starting point would be:

```
for word in original:
```

Comment: Okay! I'm pretty new to python, so I don't quite know how to reference the strings in the list as a variable, instead of directly (if that makes sense?)
So I would say:

'for word in original[0]'

Then continue my 'if' statements?